# Android push notification not receive when internet is ON

Tags: push-notification

1) I have implement the push notification.It works fine when device is      connected to Internet.(i-e) receive notification from server side

2)  when the device is not connected to Internet. if  server send the push message.and then when the device is connected to Internet..it not receiving the push message .. this is the problem

3) It like to implement push message like whats app..when the device is connect to Internet ..it should receive the push message..

```
public class GcmIntentService extends GcmListenerService {



    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("title");
        String post_id=data.getString("id");
        boolean pushactive= SharedPreference.getInstance().getBool(this,"pushactive");
        if(pushactive)
        generateNotification(message,post_id);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("inside GcmListenerService");
    }

    public void generateNotification(String message,String post_id)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewsDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isPush", true);
        intent.putExtra("post_id",post_id);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentTitle("EGToday")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        notificationManager.notify(m, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

how to achieve this?

This is my intent service class.

this is my manifeast

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.egt">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission android:name="com.egt.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.egt.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />





    <application
        android:name="com.egt.Constants.NetworkCall"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".View.SplashPage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:name=".View.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name=".View.NewsDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name=".View.SearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.egt" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.egt.PushNotification.GcmIntentService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.egt.PushNotification.GcmRegistration"
            android:exported="false" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: actually issue not in mobile application
please check your server side code please check following answer

Comment: please post u r server side code

Comment: actually i use wordpress plugin for pushnotification                                                                                                                                                                                                                      url:https://wordpress.org/plugins/push-notifications-for-wp/screenshots/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server side set delayWhileIdle(true)

> If the device is connected but idle, the message will still be
>   delivered right away unless the delay_while_idle flag is set to true.
>   Otherwise, it will be stored in the GCM servers until the device is
>   awake. And that's where the collapse_key flag plays a role: if there
>   is already a message with the same collapse key (and registration ID)
>   stored and waiting for delivery, the old message will be discarded and
>   the new message will take its place (that is, the old message will be
>   collapsed by the new one).

Ex.

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY,text).build();
```

Comment: This  GcmListenerService is called after 30-45 minutes after connecting to internet...